# Collect data from multiple mysql databases hosted on different servers, to a single database

Tags: mysql, database-design, analytics, bigdata, nosql

I have 50 mysql databases hosted **on different servers**.
All databases have the same structure (same schema,tables) but different data (rows).

I want to grab the data from all the 50 databases and update a main database with them, every 10'.

- **How can I achieve that or What tool do you propose for this operation?**
- **What type of database (main) should I use to store the data from the 50 databases?**

**Volume of data is high 10000-100000+ of rows for each table and database everyday

Comment: What will you do with the collected data?  I ask because the solution (multi-source replication, separate vs same table, cron vs replication, etc) may be different.